# T-Sql Like Dilemma - selecting rows w.r.t. keyword

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, sql-like

<sub>This is a sequel to my (other) dumb question that I have asked today</sub>

I have a stored proc in SQL Server which needs to select certain rows based on a keyword, like:

```
@Key varchar(5) = 'a'

select * From Products where ProductName like 'a%'
```

now, the `@Key` can contain values like `0-9` and `XYZ` apart from all the other normal characters from `A`, `B` to `W`

so when `@Key` is `XYZ` it needs to select all products which starts from letters X, Y, **OR**  Z and when its `0-9` it should select any products which starts from numbers.

so what I have is this now:

```
WHERE
(@Key='xyz' and (name like 'x%' or name like 'y%' or name like 'z%'))
or name LIKE @Keyword +'%'
```

and now, to get the proc to pickup numbers, I should do something similar to the XYZ but includes `name like '0%' or name like '1%'` ten times.

Surely, there should be a better way to ask SQL Server to select with names starting from decimal?

is this the only way to do it?

thanks.

<sub>sorry if I am asking too many questions!</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LIKE statement also allows for wild cards in a single character, eg

```
SELECT...
WHERE foo LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

will return values where foo begins with a digit.

Similarly,

```
SELECT...
WHERE foo LIKE '[aeiou]%'
```

will return values where foo begins with a vowel.

Check the [documentation for LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) - there are a few more tricks...

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
name like '[0-9]%'
```

For your other scenario you can use

```
name like '[x-z]%'
```

or

```
name like '[xyz]%'
```

In a case insensitive collation these last 2 are equivalent. However they are not the same in a case sensitive collation (`[x-z]%` would match "Yoghurt" whereas `[xyz]%` wouldn't)

Comment: hahaha! so many thanks! I am laughing at the fact that, clearly, there is still so much for me to learn!